# Use java regex to find all strings that start with '@' and end with ' ' , and not include ' ' and '@'

Tags: java, regex

I need to get all strings(not empty) starts with `@` and end with  `' '`(space) in String below:

```
String s = "@test1 @test2 @test3  @test4 @@ @test5";
```

I hope I can get all `"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"` strings.

How to do it with java regx? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex

```
@\w+
```

`\w` is similar to `[a-zA-Z\d_]`

`\w+` matches 1 to many characters which are from `[a-zA-Z\d_]`

Comment: looks good for english, but i need it support other languages like chinese. for example,  @thisis汉语 , i can get 'thisis汉语' as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Java regex `(?<=@)[^@ ]+(?= )` should do the trick. According to Regex Planet's Java regex page that regex matches `test1`, `test2`, `test3` and `test4`. (`@test5` does not end with a space, so `test5` is not matched.)

If you're OK with matching the leading `@`s and trailing s as well, you can get away with the simpler Java regex `@[^@ ]+`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it with code below:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@\\p{L}+");
```

Comment: Glad to hear that! Perhaps you might consider voting up helpful answers and accepting the most helpful one? (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) :)